# Find $Q$ in $R_2 = Q^TR_1Q$ where all matrices $R_1, R_2, Q$ are 3x3 rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, kronecker-product, frobenius-method, procrustes-problem

Can we obtain $Q$ in
$$R_2 = Q^TR_1Q$$
where $R_1, R_2, Q$ are all 3x3 rotation matrices, $R_1 \ne R2$, and $\operatorname{trace}(R_1)=\operatorname{trace}(R_2)$?

*I have a problem where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are known. I also have the ground truth of $Q$, which needs to be solved. The matrices do not commute since they are in 3D.*

I tried vectorization in an attempt to determine $Q$ from the Kronecker root of $Q^T\otimes Q^T$,

$$\operatorname{vec}(R_2) = (Q^T\otimes Q^T)\operatorname{vec}(R_1)$$

with $\otimes$ denoting the Kronecker product. However, the approach does not seem right since it results in an underdetermined system having $\operatorname{vec}(R_2) \operatorname{vec}(R_1)^\dagger$ with a unit rank and $Q^T\otimes Q^T$ with a rank of $9$.

Is $Q$ solvable and uniquely determined, leveraging the condition that all three matrices are rotations?

---

<s>I updated the title</s> *(Title was modified following a useful comment)* to consider treating this as a two-sided orthogonal Procrustes problem,
$$\underset{Q}{\operatorname{argmin}}\|Q^TR_1Q - R_2\|_F^2 \ .$$
I'm also searching the literature if the problem can be solved this way. Please help.

Comment: *"Is  solvable and uniquely determined"* --obviously can't be unique in general.  Consider $R_2:=R_1:=I$ then arbitrary $Q\in SO_3(\mathbb R)$ works.  To check if a solution exists a necessary and sufficient condition is $\text{trace}\big(R_1\big)=\text{trace}\big(R_2\big)$. Then orthogonally block diagonalize each (i.e. make use of the fact that each has eigenvalue 1 to reduce to $2\times 2$ problem).

Comment: @user8675309, thanks. I've updated the post to include non-equality ($R_1 \ne R2$), and trace equality ($\operatorname{trace}(R_1)=\operatorname{trace}(R_2)$) constraints.  Can you please expound on converting the problem to $2\times 2$?

Comment: I really don't understand why you're now calling this a Procrustean problem after my statement that an exact solution exists.  Do you understand why $R_2 =U^*R_1U$ for some $U\in SU_n(\mathbb C)$? If no: the problem is not understanding spectral theory.  The problem is only slightly more difficult when we are constrained to work over reals and when you solve this, *you will still see the solution cannot be unique.*

Comment: @user8675309, thanks for your helpful comment. I have modified the title accordingly, no more referring to it as a Procrustean problem.

Comment: I am pushing for a less calculation based approach from you. Note $R_k\in SO_3(\mathbb R)$ has an eigenvalue of 1 (why?) so $R_k\mathbf v_1^{(k)} = \mathbf v_1^{(k)}$ now extend to $V_k\in SO_3(\mathbb R)$ whose 1st column is by $\mathbf v_1^{(k)}$.  This means $R_kV_k =V_k \begin{pmatrix}1 &* \\ \mathbf 0& R'\end{pmatrix}=V_k \begin{pmatrix}1 &\mathbf 0^T \\ \mathbf 0& R'\end{pmatrix}$  where $R' \in SO_2(\mathbb R)$ and can be taken to be identical for $R_1$ and $R_2$ (why?).  For your problem see $Q:= V_1^TV_2$ satisfies.  Can you fill in the details and see why $Q$ can't be unique?